# Initialising a UIImageView with a different image depending on a variable

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView with some cells. When a cell is tapped, I set a string variable called Index to the index of the cell that was tapped. I have verified that this is working with an NSLog of Index from my UIImageView's controller. Now, what I'm trying to do is set the image of a UIImageView to an image corresponding to the cell tapped (i.e. a different image for each cell). The way I'm trying to do this (it doesn't work) is with this code in my UIImageView's controller's ViewDidLoad method:

```
if ([[TableViewController alloc] Index] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
   Display.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]; 
}
```

'Display' is the name of my UIImageView.
Is this code correct? If it is, where should I put it so that when I tap the first cell my UIImageView initialises with the image called "0.jpg"?

Comment: By the way, this works if I just have ‘Display.image = [UIImage imageNamed @"0"];‘ without the if statement.

Comment: Looks like your view has no idea what [[TableViewController alloc] Index] means then.  I think your best bet is to avoid this and use an instance variable where you set which row was selected from the tableView didSelectRow... method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your image view controller already visible (loaded) on the same screen as your table view, or are you pushing a new image view controller for each cell tap on the table view?  This makes a huge difference in how to approach this.  If you are doing the former, using viewDidLoad won't work because the view is already loaded.  You'll have to write a method to change the image, like:

```
-(void)changeImage:(NSString *)imageName {
    Display.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

If you're pushing a new image view each time, then you'll want to make an instance variable in the image view class and put this in your table view didSelectRow... method:

```
myImageView.imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", indexPath.row];
//now push your view
```

It might be helpful to post more of your code so we can see the situation with how the views are loaded.

Comment: I'm pushing a new ImageView each time.

Comment: Then I would definitely make an instance variable in your imageview class to hold the string.  Set that from your tableview class, and that will work.  Making a reference to your table view class is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I think what your if ([[TableViewController alloc] Index] isEqualToString:@"0"]) is comparing a number (Index) to a string "0".  Perhaps it should be something likes this:

if ([[TableViewController alloc] Index] == 0)